# How to order by another table column

Tags: sql, join, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables

1) **movie**

```
|id(pk),name|
============
|256    sdsd| 
|524    jmjm|
|122    dfdf|
|525    erer|
|952    tyyt|
|600    yunt|
```

2) **favorites**

```
|fid(pk),movie_id,uid   |
=========================
|1       256      454668|
|2       524      545656|
|3       122      454668|
|4       525      454668|
|5       952      454668|
|6       256      545656|
|7       625      454668|
|8       600      454668|
```

1st tables id and 2nd tables `movie_id` are same items...

My problem is.. first I want to get `movie_id where uid = 454668` then using that `movie_id`(s) I want to list `name` where `'id' = 'movie_ids` (list we got from last query) from first table but order by second tables `fid`...

How I can go???

I am not good at inner and joins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` for that.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM movie m JOIN favorites f 
ON m.id = f.movie_id
WHERE f.uid = 454668 
ORDER BY f.fid
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71635/4)